# What exactly is "bulk data" in WADO-RS standard?

Tags: dicom, dicomweb

[Referring to http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/2016e/output/chtml/part18/sect_6.5.html]

When we are talking about WADO-RS, NEMA mentions that:

Every request (we'll leave out /metadata & /rendered requests for now) can have *accept-type* of three types:

*1. multipart/related; type="application/dicom" [dcm-parameters]*
------- **(DICOM File format as mentioned in PS3.10)**

*2. multipart/related; type="application/octet-stream" [dcm-parameters]*
------- **(Bulk data)**

*3. multipart/related; type="{media-type}" [dcm-parameters]*
------- **(Bulk data)**

For all these accept types, response is created as multipart with each part corresponding to a particular Instance. Now I understand the first case (application/dicom) in which we'll have fill each response part with each SOP Instance's .dcm counterpart. (for e.g., if the WADO RS is for a Study, then the multipart response will have one part for each SOP Instance's Dicom File Stream)
But when it comes to the bulk data I have few questions:

1. What exactly is bulk-data in WADO-RS standard? Is it only the 7FE00010 tag, or is it all the binary tags of an SOP Instance combined into one single binary data?
2. If it is just 7FE00010, then there will be one http response part each for every SOP Instance. Then how will the WADO-RS client come to know which bulk data is of which SOP Instance?

Information about this is limited on the internet. Hence asking here.
If any one has any article about this, that's welcome too.

Ps: I am new to DICOM/DICOMWeb

Answer (score 2):

What I've generally used is to look at what's included (or should it be excluded?) in the [Composite Instance Retrieve Without Bulk Data](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part04/chapter_Z.html) service class:

- (7FE0,0010) Pixel Data
- (7FE0,0008) Float Pixel Data
- (7FE0,0009) Double Float Pixel Data
- (0028,7FE0) Pixel Data Provider URL
- (5600,0020) Spectroscopy Data
- (60xx,3000) Overlay Data
- (50xx,3000) Curve Data
- (50xx,200C) Audio Sample Data
- (0042,0011) Encapsulated Document
- (5400,1010) Waveform Data (within a (5400,0100) Waveform Sequence)

Comment: Then how is the request made from a client? It is supposed to be same as that for normal dicom retrieve but with accept-type set as the 2nd/3rd option in my question.